# << Operator Appending String to List Acting Strange - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, append

I'm trying to append a string (made up of characters from another string iterated through a for loop) to an array. But for some reason when I output the items of the array in the end they're all off.

Here's my output for the code I have:

```
r
racecar
a
aceca
c
cec
e
c
a
r
Final list:
racecar
racecar
acecar
acecar
cecar
cecar
ecar
car
ar
r
```

I tried adding a empty string to the end of my statement like so,

```
list << string_current + ""
```

and it seems to fix the problem. Does anyone know why this is?

```
def longest_palindrome(s)
  n = s.length
  max_string = ""
  max_string_current = ""
  string_current = ""
  list = []
  counter = 0
  for i in (0...n)
    for j in (i...n)
      string_current << s[j]
      # puts "string_current: #{string_current}"
      if is_palindrome(string_current)
        counter += 1
        puts string_current
        list << string_current
      end
    end
    string_current = ""
  end
  puts "Final list:"
  list.each do |item|
    puts "#{item}"
  end
end

def is_palindrome(string)
  for i in (0..string.length/2)
    if string[i] != string[string.length-1-i]
      return false
    end
  end
  return true
end

longest_palindrome("racecar")
```

I thought that the items in my final list should be idential to those being put into the list during.

```
list << string_current
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
string_current << s[j]
```

modifies the string in-place. That means that this:

```
list << string_current
```

can put a correct string into `list` and then that string can be modified later.

When you append your blank string:

```
list << string_current + ""
```

you're creating a brand new string (`string_current + ""`) and then pushing that new string onto `list` so you're doing this:

```
tmp = string_current + ""
list << tmp
```

A couple simple ways around your problem would be explicitly dup'ing the string:

```
if is_palindrome(string_current)
  counter += 1
  puts string_current
  list << string_current.dup # <--------------------
end
```

or using `+=` instead of `<<` on `string_current`:

```
for i in (0...n)
  string_current = ''
  for j in (i...n)
    string_current += s[j]
```

You should also consider replacing your `for` loops (which are rare in Ruby) with methods from [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html). I don't want to go down a refactoring rabbit hole right now so I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have fixed it by

```
list << string_current.dup
```

but the real problem is your

```
string_current << s[j]
```

Try out (for instance in *irb*) the following example:

```
list=[]
str='ab'
list << str
str << 'x'
puts list
```

You will see that the list contains now `'abx'`, not `'ab'`.

The reason is that the list contains an object reference (pointer) to the string, and when you do the `str << 'x'`, you don't create a new object, but modify the existing one, and `list` hence sees the updated version.